# Python Beautifulsoup Script в словарь Python

Tags: python, json, beautiful-soup

Подскажите как переделать объект Script в словарь Python

```
file = open('D:/html/trabl/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')
category = soup.find("script")
```

вывод category на данном этапе:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@id" : "https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
  "name": "Замуж за Бузову: Лебедев, Зеленский, Наумов и Коробков борются за первое свидание (выпуск 2) на Rutube",
  "description": "Первая четверка парней борется за первое свидание с Ольгой Бузовой. Ребятам предстоит на мини гондоле приплыть на другую сторону берега к Ольге Бузовой и вот кто сделает это первым - выйдет в финал данного испытания и будет бороться за первый тет-а-тет с телеведущей Бузовой.. Фрагмент из 1 сезон   2 выпуск  программы Замуж за Бузову ",
  "@type" : "TVClip",

  "partOfSeries" : {
    "@type" : "TVSeries",
    "name" : "Замуж за Бузову",
    "url": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/tv/7656/"
  },

  "partOfSeason" : {
    "@type" : "TVSeason",
    "seasonNumber" : "1"
  },

"partOfEpisode" : {
    "@type" : "TVEpisode",
    "episodeNumber" : "2"
  },

  "image" : "https://pic.rutube.ru/video/00/d2/00d2e173aeb89893be7012a31f9b22ed.png",
  "director": [],
  "actor": [
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/33143/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430 \u0411\u0443\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/135794/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0439 \u041d\u0430\u0443\u043c\u043e\u0432"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/149597/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441 \u041b\u0435\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0435\u0432"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/149598/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0417\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/149604/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0438\u043d \u041a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043a\u043e\u0432"
    }
],
  "video": {
    "@type": "VideoObject",
    "description": "Первая четверка парней борется за первое свидание с Ольгой Бузовой. Ребятам предстоит на мини гондоле приплыть на другую сторону берега к Ольге Бузовой и вот кто сделает это первым - выйдет в финал данного испытания и будет бороться за первый тет-а-тет с телеведущей Бузовой.",
    "duration": "PT1M49S",
    "url": "https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
    "name": "Замуж за Бузову: Лебедев, Зеленский, Наумов и Коробков борются за первое свидание (выпуск 2)",
    "thumbnail": "00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://pic.rutube.ru/video/00/d2/00d2e173aeb89893be7012a31f9b22ed.png",
    "uploadDate" : "2018-09-09T20:08:34",  
    "embedUrl": "https://rutube.ru/play/embed/11369801",
   "interactionStatistic": [

   {"@type": "InteractionCounter",
   "interactionType": "http://schema.org/WatchAction",
   "userInteractionCount": "1399"
  } ]
  },

  "datePublished": "2018-09-09T21:57:48",
   "isFamilyFriendly": "true",
   "genre": "Телепередачи",

   "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "WatchAction",
    "target": [
      {
        "url": "https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
        "inLanguage": "ru",
         "actionPlatform": [
        "http://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/MobileWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/IOSPlatform"
      ]},
        {
          "url": "android-app://ru.rutube.app/http/rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
          "inLanguage": "ru",
          "actionPlatform": "http://schema.org/AndroidPlatform"
      }
    ]
}}
}
</script>
```

Никак не получается достать "genre": "Телепередачи",

Comment: `print(d['genre'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно получить содержимое тега `<script>` и преобразовать в словарь с помощью `json.loads()`

HTML строка:

```
html = """
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@id" : "https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
  "name": "Замуж за Бузову: Лебедев, Зеленский, Наумов и Коробков борются за первое свидание (выпуск 2) на Rutube",
  "description": "Первая четверка парней борется за первое свидание с Ольгой Бузовой. Ребятам предстоит на мини гондоле приплыть на другую сторону берега к Ольге Бузовой и вот кто сделает это первым - выйдет в финал данного испытания и будет бороться за первый тет-а-тет с телеведущей Бузовой.. Фрагмент из 1 сезон   2 выпуск  программы Замуж за Бузову ",
  "@type" : "TVClip",

  "partOfSeries" : {
    "@type" : "TVSeries",
    "name" : "Замуж за Бузову",
    "url": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/tv/7656/"
  },

  "partOfSeason" : {
    "@type" : "TVSeason",
    "seasonNumber" : "1"
  },

"partOfEpisode" : {
    "@type" : "TVEpisode",
    "episodeNumber" : "2"
  },

  "image" : "https://pic.rutube.ru/video/00/d2/00d2e173aeb89893be7012a31f9b22ed.png",
  "director": [],
  "actor": [
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/33143/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430 \u0411\u0443\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/135794/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0439 \u041d\u0430\u0443\u043c\u043e\u0432"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/149597/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441 \u041b\u0435\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0435\u0432"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/149598/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439 \u0417\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"
    }, 
    {
        "sameAs": "https://rutube.ru/metainfo/person/149604/", 
        "@type": "Person", 
        "name": "\u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0438\u043d \u041a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043a\u043e\u0432"
    }
],
  "video": {
    "@type": "VideoObject",
    "description": "Первая четверка парней борется за первое свидание с Ольгой Бузовой. Ребятам предстоит на мини гондоле приплыть на другую сторону берега к Ольге Бузовой и вот кто сделает это первым - выйдет в финал данного испытания и будет бороться за первый тет-а-тет с телеведущей Бузовой.",
    "duration": "PT1M49S",
    "url": "https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
    "name": "Замуж за Бузову: Лебедев, Зеленский, Наумов и Коробков борются за первое свидание (выпуск 2)",
    "thumbnail": "00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://pic.rutube.ru/video/00/d2/00d2e173aeb89893be7012a31f9b22ed.png",
    "uploadDate" : "2018-09-09T20:08:34",  
    "embedUrl": "https://rutube.ru/play/embed/11369801",
   "interactionStatistic": [

   {"@type": "InteractionCounter",
   "interactionType": "http://schema.org/WatchAction",
   "userInteractionCount": "1399"
  } ]
  },

  "datePublished": "2018-09-09T21:57:48",
   "isFamilyFriendly": "true",
   "genre": "Телепередачи",

   "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "WatchAction",
    "target": [
      {
        "url": "https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
        "inLanguage": "ru",
         "actionPlatform": [
        "http://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/MobileWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/IOSPlatform"
      ]},
        {
          "url": "android-app://ru.rutube.app/http/rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/",
          "inLanguage": "ru",
          "actionPlatform": "http://schema.org/AndroidPlatform"
      }
    ]
}}
}
</script>
"""
```

Далее парсим. Похоже, в вашем примере есть лишняя фигурная скобка в конце, поэтому нужно обрезать ее из результата, иначе JSON парсер выдает ошибку.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


category = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

category_text = category.text[:-3]

category_dict = json.loads(category_text)
print(category_dict['@id'])
# https://rutube.ru/video/00c5b03b5fc55b70978200771a28c62f/
```